# How to integrate config files after deploy?

Tags: json, python-3.x, configuration, config

I have the following folder structure:

```
    helloworld /
    │
    ├── helloworld.py
    ├── conf.json
    ├── setup.py
    ├── parameterManager.py
```

The functionality is very basic-
My helloworld.py read a parameter from the conf.json and print it :

```
    from parameterManger import return_params as pm
    what_to_print = pm("print")
    print(what_to_print)
```

My parameterManager.py helps me read the json as following:

```
import os
import josn
def return_params (ParameterName=None, conf_file_name='/conf.json',):
    try:
        ConfFolder = os.path.dirname(__file__)
        ConfFile=ConfFolder + conf_file_name
        with open(ConfFile) as json_data_file:
            Data = json.load(json_data_file)
            if ParameterName is None:
                return Data
            ParamterValue=Data[ParameterName]
            return ParamterValue
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

It works perfect until I "deploy"

in another project I git+http://gitlab.lan/username/helloworld.git
but I get always the Error

```
'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'D:\\path_to_new_project\\venv\\lib\\site-packages\\conf.json'
```

I can think on "dirty" solutions, but I am 100% sure there is a "pythonic" way to share files between projects.Can some share with me what is the correct way doing it?

Comment: How you "deploy" it? Can you offer more information?

Comment: In deploy I meant - sharing the project with my team/colleagues in a way they can "pip install helloworld"   ( not in a  pypi way, but through git). That is the reason for the setup.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I think you should pack `helloworld` as a package, like:

```
helloworld
├── helloworld
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── config.json
│   ├── helloworld.py
│   └── parameterManager.py
└── setup.py
```

Then, add `config.json` to your `package_data` in `setup.py`.

```py
from setuptools import setup

...

PACKAGES = [
  'helloworld'
]

PACKAGE_DATA = {
  'helloworld' : ['config.json']
}

...

setup(
    ...
    packages=PACKAGES,
    package_data=PACKAGE_DATA,
    ...
)
```